# checking text area for ling and changing them into hyperlink

Tags: javascript

So I have this function here:

```
function ShowMessage()
{
   var themessege = document.getElementById("Form").textarea1.value;
   var dat = new Date(); 
   var fileName = document.getElementById("theFile").value;
   var image = '<img src="' + fileName + '"/>' + '<br>';
   document.getElementById("Form").textarea1.value = ""; 
   document.getElementById("Form").countdown.value = "160"; 
   document.getElementById("theFile").value = "";
   if (themessege==null || themessege=="") 
       {
       alert("There is no text to submit, please fill out the text box");
       return false;
       }

   document.getElementById("blog").innerHTML = document.getElementById("blog").innerHTML + image +  "Guest post: " + themessege + "<br />" +  dat +"<br />";   
}
```

I can get the text from the text area, as well as the image the user uploads. I'm wondering how I can divide the strings in the text area into subsrtings to check if they start with "www" or "htt".

This is what I've written so far:

```
function linkify(inputText) {
   var replaceText, replacePattern1, replacePattern2;

   //URLs starting with http://, https://
   replacePattern1 =https;
   replacedText = inputText.replace(replacePattern1, '<a href= ></a>');

   //URLs starting with "www." (without // before it, or it'd re-link the ones done above).
   replacePattern2 = www.;
   replacedText = replacedText.replace(replacePattern2, <a href="http:  ></a>');
   var x = getelementbyid("blog");
   for(var i = 0;i < x.length;i++){
      if(blog.charAt(i) == replacePattern1){
      return replacedText;
      }
   }
   else if(blog.charAt(i) == replacePattern2){
     return replacedText;
   }
}
```

I know that the `charAt(i)` only checks for 1 letter....

Most of the answers that I found were on PHP, I'm trying to find a solution using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

linkify function is not correctly written. try this one.

```
function linkify(inputText) {
var regUrl = /(http:[\d]{0,4}\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU)/;

return inputText.replace(regUrl,'<a href="" />');
}
;
alert(linkify('string containing link www.google.com'));// output: string containing link <a href="" />
```

Comment: Your function just replaces the link with <a href="" /> and judging by the funciton name, I don't believe that's what he wants. I believe he wants it to actually become a clickable hyper-link.

Answer (score 1):

Your linkify function is all wrong. All your variables contain references to variables that don't exist! Put quotes around them to make them strings.

What does this `replacedText = inputText.replace(replacePattern1, '<a href= ></a>');` do?

Say inputText is 'https://example.com' and assuming you corrected your variables, so that `replacePattern1 === 'https'`
You find the https and replace it with . What does the final product look like?

`replacedText === '<a href= ></a>://example.com';`

Same thing happens with the second replace pattern.

Further, there is nothing like getelementbyid. It's [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById). JavaScript is case-sensitive. It returns a single element with an id, so you can't loop through it.

Please, learn JavaScript before you try writing JavaScript code. [Here's a good resource to start](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide). Also, read [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do), by Douglas Crockford.

---

Answering your question, here is the code you should use:

```
string.replace(/(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>")
```

The `https?` means either http or https. The `[^\s]+` means anything but a whitespace character. The `$1` means the entire matched URL.
[This is a good reference for Regular Expressions in JavaScript](http://www.learn-javascript-tutorial.com/RegularExpressions.cfm)

This will allow for https and http URLs containing letters and numbers and convert the URLs into links.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EpsXt/)

Comment: thanks, i am trying to learn JavaScript, my page is working fine, and i thank you for the clickable link, but is there a way we can convert the strings inside the text area i have into substring so that i may add the if statements to replace string that start with www and http/ https? thats my main problem...

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to say. Example please?

Comment: ok i have a test are where the user will enter random text, while hes typing he enters a link for example www.google.com or whatever, when he clicks submit the link www.google.com is shown as a normal text, not a clickable link, im trying to figure out a way to loop through the text in the textarea, locate text that start with either "www" or "hhtp" and convert the whole text into clickable link
i hope that make it clear

Comment: So you want all of the text *in the textarea* to be clickable?

Comment: nope just the ones that start with http or www in other words just URL links

Comment: You can't do that in a textarea. Would a contenteditable div be fine?

Comment: i know you cant do that on the text area im using

Comment: i know you cant do that on the text area im using
   <input type ="button" onclick="ShowMessage()" value ="Update" />
to move the text out of the text area onto page, a code that would locate words that start with www or http 
i can add an if or a switch statement to change it to hyper links using 
"variable name".replace(/(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>")

Comment: I don't need more code. I need to understand what you want to do. All I can understand form what you've said is that there will be text in a textarea which will contain a link as well. You want a function that moves the text from the textarea to a div, and you want to hyper-link any URLs. Is that correct?

Comment: yes that is correct, i already have the function that moves the text from the textarea, im just missing the hyper-link any URLs

Comment: thank you i will give it a shot :) sorry for all the bothering man,

Comment: Sure. Mark it as the correct answer if, well, if it is the correct answer.